# Python regex extract groups between different potential expressions

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to extract groups that are between characters or sets of characters. The issue is that some characters in groups can also be in the sets of characters used to extract the groups. Here is what I mean:
My sentence is something like:
`text = '[[aaa / bbb (T1=T2)] / [bbb (T1=T2) / bbb (T1>T2)]]'`
At the end I'd like to get a list like:
`['aaa', 'bbb (T1=T2)', 'bbb (T1=T2)', 'bbb (T1>T2)']`
so I should 'cut' at `\[*`, `\]*` or `\s\/\s`.
I've tried in Python `re.findall(r'[\[*|\]*|\s\/\s](.*?)[\[*|\]*|\s\/\s]', text)` but the output is `['', '', 'bbb', '', '', 'bbb', '', 'bbb', '']`. I have tried many things actually, and of course I searched a lot on the internet before posting. Then, on https://regexr.com/ I realized that the pattern `\s\/\s` was correctly detected, but as soon as I added the range characters `[` and `]` to do `[\[*|\]*|\s\/\s]`, all single spaces where also detected, because the range sees `\s` and says "ok let's split at every space". That makes sense, but that's not how I need to split my sentences. I've tried adding brackets or parentheses around `\s\/\s` but that doesn't work, in https://regexr.com/ or in Python.
Do you have an idea of how to include a *set* of characters of an *expression* in the possible patterns to extract groups?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If the single square brackets should be part of the match, you could capture in a group what is in between and then use split.

- The split pattern `\s+/\s+` matches a forward slash between 1 or more whitespace characters.
- The match pattern `\[([^][]*)]` matches `[` till the first occurrence of `]` using a negated character class and captures in group 1 what is in between.

For example

```
import re

text = '[[aaa / bbb (T1=T2)] / [bbb (T1=T2) / bbb (T1>T2)]]'
pattern = r"\[([^][]*)]"
res = []

for s in re.findall(pattern, text):
    res += re.split(r"\s+/\s+", s)

print(res)
```

Output

```
['aaa', 'bbb (T1=T2)', 'bbb (T1=T2)', 'bbb (T1>T2)']
```

See the group 1 match in this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ldGaPP/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/w2F1XU).

Comment: I needed to not have the single brackets, but thanks for your answer.
However I had a different results from what you show:
```['aaa', 'bbb (T1=T2)]', 'bbb (T1=T2)', 'bbb (T1>T2)]']```

Comment: @AlexisCllmb Ah I see, in the code in the answer there was a `]`  still inside the capture group. I have updated it.